# Google Maps api custom tiles for fictional video game world

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use the Google Maps v3 api to generate an interactive Google Map interface that uses custom tiles for a map from a video game. The app needs to be able to zoom-in out and display the proper tiles for each zoom level as well.

I'm looking for some resources or a tutorial on how to accomplish this. The Google Maps v3 API appears to only discuss using custom tiles that lay on top of the normal Google Maps tiles. That wouldn't make sense in my application since my map is for a fictional world and wouldn't line up with anything in the real world maps. Perhaps I'm just not seeing what I need in the API guide...

Comment: For anyone interested in an answer I gave up on Google Maps API and switched to using http://leafletjs.com. Much more powerful, easier to develop with, and well maintained with good documentation. Never looked back.

Comment: Any reason why google maps/maps engine didn't suffice?

Comment: Throughout development with Leaflet there were MANY cases where I accomplished what I needed in 1 line of code compared to what would take 30+ lines of code in Google Maps. Leaflet is Open Source. Actively developed on Github. Etc. It's solid. Google Maps API is pretty much a black box.

Comment: @Jakobud, what did you use to create your custom tiles?

Comment: I just pulled the tiles from the game files (the project this was for was http://ps2maps.com). I put together some Python scripts that used ImageMagick to refactor and resize the tiles and generated everything I needed.

Answer (score 8):

Check out the [ImageMapType](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ImageMapType) class in the reference. There's a nifty example showing [Moon](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image) tiles.

One of my favourite applications is [The Internet map](http://internet-map.net), the developer wrote a pretty sweet [article](http://the-internet-map.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/the-internet-maps-web-architecture.html) on how it was developed.

Comment: Unfortunately the Moon example has infinitely horizontally tiling layout, which I was hoping to avoid. So that didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to either cut up your custom game map image into the appropriate file/directory structure that makes integration into Maps API easy ([here's an example](http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1184658) using Photoshop and some example HTML/JS code). Or use a more friendly tool like [TileMill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/manual/exporting/), but this expects data in a standard spatial data format and you probably don't have your game map stored in such a format. If you can go that route, they also provide a Node.js-based server called [TileServe](https://github.com/mapbox/tilestream) that makes integration a cinch.

If you are expecting a boatload of traffic, then maybe look at [Google Maps Engine](http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/products/mapsengine.html) to host your custom game map image directly in Google's infrastructure.